# const in C: Cannot allocate an array of constant size 0

Tags: c

A small piece of code:

```
void func()
{
   const int BUF_SIZE = 5;
   char scale[BUF_SIZE];
}
```

This code is built fine under C++, but under C I have an errors:

```
error C2057: expected constant expression
error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
```

Why?

Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ 2008

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure, that this is fine in C++, but not in C? Isn't it the opposite ?

Comment: @Kiril I'm pretty sure this is fine in C++ since i use this quite a lot in embedded code. I'm not really sure if this is legal in C89 though.

Comment: Yes, I am. It gives no errors if I set the file extention to ".cpp" but gives mentioned errors in case of ".c" extention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C (all variants, I believe), a `const` is, ironically, not a *constant expression* in C. In pre-C99, array lengths must be a constant expression.

However, C99 has the concept of "variable length arrays", so if you're compiling with a C99-compliant compiler, your code should be valid even though `BUF_SIZE` is not a constant expression.

Comment: Not valid C89 to be precise. It is perfectly OK in C99.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I was just checking that.  Could you tell me where in the C99 standard it allows this?

Comment: @Oli C99 allows variable sized arrays, so it doesn't matter that BUF_SIZE isn't a constant expression.

Comment: @Michael And why exactly would that be invalid in C99?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Ah, that's true.  Let me reword my answer.

Comment: @EvgK Dynamically allocated, stack based array. In C99 that is. In C89 it is invalid code.

Comment: Maybe we should note that the VC-compiler doesn't support C99.

Comment: @Michael I think you should actually read the question not just one line from it. Especially when the line is just a confused rambling of MSVC.

Comment: @Oli: But Visual Studio help system shows me an examples of such const declarations

Comment: @EvgK: Can you provide a link to an MSDN help page?

Comment: @Oli: I found it in a local help system. The link is  ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/MS.MSDNQTR.v90.en/dv_vclang/html/bb4c6744-1dd7-40a8-b4eb-f5585be30908.htm   but I'm afraid it is not valid on your machine

Comment: @EvgK: Your local help in VS should have an exact equivalent on the online MSDN.

Comment: @EvgK: That doesn't change my answer.  A `const` is not a constant-expression.

Comment: "The const type qualifier declares an object to be nonmodifiable". Isn't it the same as "to be constant-expression"?

Comment: @EvgK: No.  The C standard gives a precise definition of the term "constant-expression" (see e.g. section 6.6 of the C99 standard).

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 5
void func(){
    char scale[BUF_SIZE];
}
```

That will do what you need

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, use `enum { BUF_SIZE = 5 };` so that the debugger knows about it.